# Objective-c NavigationBar color change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Can someone tell me how I can set the colour of a navigation bar in a view controller?

I used this:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;

[navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Can someone can tell me what is `tintColor` and how it differs from the `backgroundColor`?

Comment: The documentation has all this information:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html . Look at the barTintColor property in order to change the navigation bar background colour.

Comment: "Can someone can tell me what is tintColor and how it differs from the backgroundColor" Actually for iOS 7 it is the difference between `backgroundColor` and `barTintColor` that you should worry about; `tintColor` is unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Change the background color of the navigation bar is easy. For example, next code changes it to blue :

```
[ self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor :
                     [ UIColor colorWithRed : ( 0x0  / 255 )
                                      green : ( 0x0  / 255 )
                                       blue : ( 0xff / 255 )
                                              alpha : 1 ] ];
```

You can add the previous code to your viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

To change the nav bar color use:

```
//Custom Navbar using image
UIImage *navbar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbar forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

//Navbar color
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

//Change the text color
NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIColor whiteColor],     NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];
```

Taken from: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/ios-custom-ui-series-tabbar-navbar/ by Rob Whitlow

Comment: The OP doesn't ask about `UITabBar`. The question explicitly states that the OP is interested in setting the colour of the navigation bar.